Shepherd.js - How to bring the arrow to another edge?
Shepherd.js
I am trying to get the arrow on the left edge (right edge of the tooltip/bubble) to point towards "Jobs I'm Working". 
Please don't ask what I have tried as I don't know what to try, there's nothing in the documentation about this.
I am trying to do it through the CSS since I don't know if it can be done through javascript.
                /* SPECIAL CUSTOMIZATIONS */
            [data-shepherd-step-id="jobs-working"] .shepherd-arrow {
                /* Move the arrow towards the left edge */
                left: 10px;
                /* Adjust the default translation */
                transform: translateX(0);
            }


Try this:
[data-shepherd-step-id="jobs-working"] .shepherd-arrow {
  left: -10px; /* Move the arrow slightly to the left */
  transform: translateX(-100%); /* Adjust the default translation */
}

